# Route RDP Through One Server

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-gateway

I have been trying to come up with a solution to enable something akin to "Remote Resources" through RDP where we can have a collection of remote desktops (residing in a remote network, such as AWS or GCP) that cannot be reached from the outside world except through one server.

I have been looking at Remote Desktop Gateway, Connection Broker, Web Access, etc... but am not sure what the "smart" way is to go about doing this.

Basically, the idea is to have the one server that users can log into and then access remote resources that reside on the remote network next to the "exposed" server.

Any thoughts or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Question: Can you spend money on public IP's to each instance?

If not still you can do this by single IP adress through port Forwarding

Linux Kvm and some routes for port can help you on this.

It is the basic idea you can then also use Windows active directory for authentication and you can bring all the instances in one domain.

Comment: Cost isn’t necessarily the issue. What we would like to do is to be able to use one point of entrance that will allow us to streamline where users can connect without giving out a bunch of IP addresses while locking down servers to local connections only.

Comment: Yes you can achieve it by port forwarding on every port it can be your resource or server. But you still need one Static IP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want two Nic's and then setup a bridge.